# Transition effects in Powerpoint slides are leaving the screen blank for half of the slide duration

Tags: slideshow, microsoft-powerpoint-2003

I have a set of Powerpoint slides which have a 'Fade' transition between them and a preset slide duration of 10 seconds.

The content of the slide only appears after about five seconds on each slide. I have tried adjusting the transition duration and 'applying to all' slides but it makes no difference.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you set any Animation effects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Powerpoint seems to be ignoring your adjustments to Effect Duration, try the below:

1. Create a new empty slide show.
2. Copy and paste the contents of each slide into the new slide slow.
3. Under 'Transitions', set your 'Advance Slide after...' to (say) 10 seconds and Duration to (say) 00.70 seconds and click 'Apply to All'.
4. Test the slide show (F5).